# extract from sqlite

Tags: file, sqlite, extract

i have a sqlite database created from the honeypot. the database contains malware files. how can i extract these files from the sqlite database. please if someone can help

Comment: Extract with what? A Java program? A .NET program? Just extract the data with SQLite's command line interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

You can dump the whole database with:

```
echo .dump | sqlite3 database.sqlite > database.dump
```

Or just view the structure with:

```
echo .schema | sqlite3 database.sqlite
```

To get the files, you'll probably need a small script to extract the BLOBs into files. Post the schema of the database if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

The `sqlite3` command can easily interrogate an sqlite3 database and the `.dump` command will allow you to dump a given table, and the `.output` command will let you select a filename for the output before dumping.

If the data came from a honeypot, be very careful about the tools you use to inspect the contents: flaws have been found in terminals that allow malicious content to gain privileges on the system. Simply using 'cat' to inspect a file on such a terminal could grant the malicious program your complete set of privileges.

So, at a minimum step, please at least use an unprivileged user account with *no* access to other data on the system. Using a tool such as AppArmor, SMACK, TOMOYO, SELinux, LIDS, to confine your tools to a small subset of system resources would be a good idea too. Virtualization could also work, but there have been plenty of 'breakouts' from those tools as well.